# sorting a JSON return into UITableView Sections and Rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to sort a JSON return into multiple sections according to each day. Here is the JSON return,

```
sales =     (
                {
            "dis_dollars" = 0;
            "dis_percent" = 0;
            id = 111;
            saleDay = 5;
            saleMonth = 1;
            saleTime = "20:02:39";
            saleYear = 2014;
            "total_price" = 25;
        },
                {
            "dis_dollars" = 0;
            "dis_percent" = 0;
            id = 103;
            saleDay = 2;
            saleMonth = 1;
            saleTime = "19:13:41";
            saleYear = 2014;
            "total_price" = 79;
        },
                {
            "dis_dollars" = "0.55";
            "dis_percent" = "0.10000000149012";
            id = 101;
            saleDay = 2;
            saleMonth = 1;
            saleTime = "10:41:11";
            saleYear = 2014;
            "total_price" = 22;
        },

                {
            "dis_dollars" = 0;
            "dis_percent" = 0;
            id = 108;
            saleDay = 1;
            saleMonth = 1;
            saleTime = "11:00:00";
            saleYear = 2014;
            "total_price" = 66;
        }
    );
}
```

I can get the number of sections if I do it this way

```
//...Connect to php script and get return json object

int saleDay = 0;

//Loop through json return
for (int i = 0;i < [sales count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary* dict = [sales objectAtIndex:i];

    Sale *eachSale =[[Sale alloc]  initWithSaleId:[dict valueForKey:@"id"]
                                          saleDay:[dict valueForKey:@"saleDay"]
                                        saleMonth:[dict valueForKey:@"saleMonth"]
                                         saleYear:[dict valueForKey:@"saleYear"]
                                         saleTime:[dict valueForKey:@"saleTime"]
                                        saleTotal:[dict valueForKey:@"total_price"]
                                   saleDisDollars:[dict valueForKey:@"dis_dollars"]
                                   saleDisPercent:[dict valueForKey:@"dis_percent"]];


    NSLog(@"sale Day %@",eachSale.saleDay);
    [_salesList addObject:eachSale];

    int eachSaleDay = [eachSale.saleDay intValue];

    // if the next day is different from the one before it, add a new section.
    if (saleDay != eachSaleDay) {
        _saleDaysCount += 1;
        NSLog(@"eachSaleDay %i" ,eachSaleDay);
        NSLog(@"salesDayCount %i" ,_saleDaysCount);
    }

    saleDay = eachSaleDay;
}
```

This will give me the correct number of sections, but how do I group the objects according to the day to find out the number of rows for each section, and what objects should go in each row?

I think I need to use NSSort Descriptors but I'm not sure where I would implement it and how to access the individual day arrays.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You'd use one of the several sort functions available from NSArray and NSMutableArray.  To the novice `sortUsingFunction` may be the easiest to understand, since it's straight-up C code.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add an additional field of type NSNumber with the complete date for each `Sale` while you are looping through your results.

```
eachSale.saleDateIdentifier = @(eachSale.saleYear.intValue * 10000 +
                                eachSale.saleMonth.intValue * 100  +
                                eachSale.saleDay.intValue);
```

Now it is easy to sort and count:

```
[_salesList sortUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"saleDateIdentifier" ascending:NO]]];

NSArray *allDates = [_salesList valueForKeyPath:@"saleDateIdentifier"];
NSSet *uniqueDates = [NSSet setWithArray:allDates];
NSArray *sortedUniqueDates = [uniqueDates sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"saleDateIdentifier" ascending:NO]]];
```

Your number of sections is `sortedUniqueDates.count`. For each section you could use the `saleDateIdentifier` to format the date string in `titleForRowAtIndexPath`.

BTW, maybe you do not want to use `valueForKey` in your init method for `eachSale`. Maybe you actually mean `objectForKey`. Better even, you should type the properties of the `Sale` class and use `NSNumber` and `NSString` as appropriate.

Comment: this makes sense. I'm going to try it. Where would I implement the sortDescriptor? would it be in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView` method because I send a notif when the data loads async, to reload the table. I keep getting this error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key saleDateIdentifier`